# Error on startup after upgrading from .Net Core 3.0 preview to .Net Core 3.0 release

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am using the same code in .Net Core 3.0 preview without any problem. After updating to Core 3.0 final release, I got this error:

> System.TypeLoadException   HResult=0x80131522   Message=Method
>   'get_Info' in type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   does not have an implementation.

The line of code that has the exception is:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Googling this exception did not lead anywhere, any idea what is going on?

Comment: Code is working in the core 3.0 preview.

Comment: Could it be that even though you upgraded your project you're still using the preview packages?

Comment: try reinstall all package in project

Comment: after updating everything to release 3.0, i got exception but this time in the browser:

Comment: TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNullAttribute' from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Comment: @bobmason, please move this additional information from the comments directly to your question.

Comment: i could not edit, so i made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242652/exception-after-updating-from-preview-to-net-core-3-0-release

Answer (score 0):

Delete all previously published files (dlls are important to be deleted), upgrade all  dependencies to previews for .net core 3.0 and then publish.

Comment: Right-click on the solution and choose 'Restore Nuget Packages' to regenerate the correct framework version packages.