# "Could not load type" exception after updating from .NET Core 3.0 preview to release

Tags: c#, .net-core

I got this error in the browser after updating to .NET Core 3.0 release:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> 'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNullAttribute' from assembly
> 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

I've updated everything to the latest version, 3.0.
Is it a bug? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when using the preview SDK of .NET Core. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18005), [R00iBaard](https://github.com/R00iBaard) [left a comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18005#issuecomment-535490699) with this solution on Sep 26, 2019:

> Hey all, I resolved mine the following way:
>
> - Make sure all .NET Core runtimes and SDKs are uninstalled. Run `dotnet --info` to see. If installing 3.0.100 didn't remove the previews, go to those dirs and manually remove them. Re install (modify) the .NET Core 3.0.100 installation to be safe again.
> - Make sure you have installed VS 2019 16.3.1
>
> Error should disappear. 
> [sic]